# What's the C++ cv::Mat data attribute in python cvmat

Tags: python, c++, opencv, imread

The C++ code is:

```
using namespace cv;

m_image_mat = imread ( full_file_name );
data = m_image_mat.data
```

when I use python:

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv

img = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
cvmat = cv.fromarray(img)
```

I can get width, height, step with cvmat.width, but when I use cvmat.data

the error appear:

```
AttributeError: 'cv2.cv.cvmat' object has no attribute 'data'
```

How Can I get data attribute with cvmat as the same as C++ Mat data

thanks

Comment: But why do you want to use `cv` API instead of `cv2` API ?

Comment: @ZdaR I need use a dll, the function in dll parameter need a C++ cv::Mat data, cv2 don't hava mat, so I use cv to convert NumPy array to cvmat, want get the data attribute as the same as c++ Mat, But now I notice that the cvmat object don't has data attribute...

Comment: The Mat in Python is just a numpy array. There's no 'data' member